# Syntax highlighting in MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

Is it possible to create a plugin or addin for MS Word that allows a section of text to be selected and then a custom "Highlighting" function to be applied to it.

I want this to all be within MS Word not a cut and past from another application.

If possible, any suggestions on where I could find some direction on how to do this ( using C# )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA - Visual Basic for Applications is your tool for this type of work in Office. It stays self-contained as well.

Shows manipulating text.

http://computerprogramming.suite101.com/article.cfm/introduction_to_vba_for_ms_word

VBA Tutorial:

http://jy.fridaynight.co.il/pages/dev/WordVBA.php

Bunch of examples.

http://www.thezcorp.com/VBACodeSamples.aspx

A Cornucopia:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/CatalogVBA-Excel-Access-Word.htm

Now that you know what to search for as well, hopefully you are on your way.

EDIT: Found this code example:

```
Sub ChangeColor
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Highlight = True
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Color = wdColorBrightGreen
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

HTH